# jQuery works fine on localhost but not on server

Tags: jquery

I have used a jQuery plugin for photo upload and validation of a field in codeigniter. It works on my local server, but when I upload it - it does not work. (I saw phpinfo() jqueryenable server).

There is no problem with the url link of jQuery; it's getting it fine, but it's not working.
The link is:

http://www.bdshop247.com/StoneBollards/admin/admins/add_product.

How can I solve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Your main jQuery file stops after

```
[ 2, "<table><tbody>", "</tbody></table>" ] ||
```

Upload it again, this time upload all of it.

Comment: I dont understand!! please describe a little more.

Comment: I am new at Jquery its not gonna be helpful for me. U got the problem  please describe then it will be much more helpful for me

Comment: The end of your jquery-blah-blah.js file is missing. Upload the **complete** file. This doesn't require knowledge of jQuery, JavaScript, or even HTML.